# Does rails touch the database before building a form from form helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

Working through the rails tutorial and it says

> When constructing a form using form_for(@user), Rails uses POST if @user.new_record? is true and PATCH if it is false.

So when it renders the html is it hitting the database and when does it do that exactly? What comes right before?

Comment: Considering the fact that [*new_record?*](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/new_record%3F) is an *AR method* that *checks for existence of a record*, I believe it will hit the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, it doesn't hit the database, you can check for yourself in the console,

```
old = User.last
new = User.new
```

Only the `old` hits the database, whereas, `new` just creates the object of class `User`, let's go further..

```
old.new_record?
#=> false
new.new_record?
#=> true
```

See, no query is hit to the database, similarly, when you pass the `@user` object to form, it checks for `new_record?` but without hitting the db.

So, how does it determine this? My wild guess, it checks for `id`/`primary_key` not `nil`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev would like to comment on my *wild guess*? :)

Answer (score 1):

Returns true if this object hasn't been saved yet – that is, a record for the object doesn't exist in the database yet; otherwise, returns false.

[Refer Here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-new_record-3F)

Comment: so, what do you conclude out of this?

Comment: @Md. Farhan Memon It's the same as your answer but this the explanation which is written on the Ruby API.